# How can I open a Div when navigating to it?

Tags: javascript, html, anchor

I would like to show the contents of a div when I navigate to it via a URL.  Currently the Div contents are revealed onclick.

How would I get the Div contents to be revealed when using a URL with anchor  to navigate to the main title in the ?

Here's javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function(){

//Set default open/close settings
$('.acc_container').hide(); //Hide/close all containers
//$('.acc_trigger:first').addClass('active').next().show(); //Add "active" class to first trigger, then show/open the immediate next container

//On Click
$('.acc_trigger').click(function(){
if( $(this).next().is(':hidden') ) { //If immediate next container is closed...
    $('.acc_trigger').removeClass('active').next().slideUp(); //Remove all .acc_trigger classes and slide up the immediate next container
    $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideDown(); //Add .acc_trigger class to clicked trigger and slide down the immediate next container
}
return false; //Prevent the browser jump to the link anchor
});

});
</script>
```

here's my html

```
<h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="#">Some Title Goes Here</a></h2>
<div class="acc_container">
    <div class="block">
    <h3>Strap Line Goes here</h3>
         Text content goes here
    </div>
</div>

<h2 class="acc_trigger"><a href="#">Another title Goes Here</a></h2>
<div class="acc_container">
    <div class="block">
    <h3>Another Strap Line Goes here</h3>
         Some more text content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a hash (e.g. url.com/page.html#otherStuff) then read the location.hash

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

If you're using a query (e.g. url.com/page.html?otherStuff) use the location.search

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_search.asp

Put the code below the DIV that you want to show, so the element has been created. Then just do a simple `if(hash == "#otherStuff"){ /* Do stuff */ }` Where in "Do stuff" you would just run the open function.

Comment: Thank you David.  I'm afraid Im very new to all this.  Could you possibly show me how to do this?

Comment: No, because I don't know your hashtag or function name. I'm not trying to be mean, but if you don't know how to write an if statement, you need to back up a bit an learn form the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

listen to the `hashchange` event which is triggered on the `window` object. then you can show the div or do what you want with it.

Something along the lines of this;

```
<a href="#about">About</a>
<div id="mydiv_about" style="display:none">
</div>
<a href="#media">Media</a>
<div id="mydiv_media" style="display:none">
</div>
```

and some javascript

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function(){
    document.getElementById("mydiv_"+document.location.hash.substr(1)).style.display="block";
},false);
```

//edit
updated to reflect a working example

Comment: Thanks japrescot.  Im not really sure what Im doing here.  Can you show me how I would make that code work.

Comment: Thanksyou.  I can't seem to get it to work when I integrate into my code as originally posted.  Im sure your code is fine, it's my lack of experience.